# Separate digits from text in Python

Tags: python, string, list, split, numbers

I'm trying to separate numbers from a string in Python such as this example:

```
text = "Compute the average of 5,7". (I want to get a list [5,7])
```

(the comma between the numbers is a must) I've tried using:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in text.split() if i.isdigit()]
```

It works when the numbers aren't separated by the comma but when written with a comma I just receive an empty list.

Comment: Perhaps you can use: numbers = [int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]

Comment: 5,7 is not an int

Comment: By the way do you want the numbers or do you actually need the comma?

Comment: @DaniMesejo He says he wants a list of the numbers.

Comment: @Barmar then a simple regex for extracting digits should be enough right?

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to find two integers separated by comma.

```
import re

m = re.search(r'(\d+),(\d+)', text)
if m:
    numbers = [int(x) for x in m.groups()]
```

Comment: As an extension, consider `re.findall()` and testing if more groups are found than expected

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = "Compute the average of 5,7"
nums = [int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]
print(nums)
# prints [5, 7]
```

Comment: However, the OP requires *digits* to be separated.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('.*(\d,\d).*', text).group(1)
'5,7'
```

Comment: You don't need `.*`